# How can I broadcast a message event to all members of a channel in Pusher?

Tags: angular, socket.io, pusher, pusher-js

I'm trying to design a chat app using Pusher and Angular. I've managed to set up the channel and send messages. However, the message event broadcasts to every client except the sender.

How do I broadcast to ALL members of the channel including the sender?

```
this.channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', (info) => {
  console.log(info);
});



this.channel.bind('client-message', (msg)=>{
  
  this.pusherMessages.next(new Message(msg.msg , msg.id , msg.date));

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to send client-events to the message sender, however as the sender already "knows" what the message is then you could just add the message to the message array when you send the message to the other chat participants.

However for your chat use case I would recommend sending the message to a server first and then broadcasting this back to the chat channel (and thereby each participant including the sender).

The reason for this is because it makes it more easier to manage persistence and guaranteeing each message has the same id and timestamp.

What I would do is send each message back to a server first e.g. POST server/api/messages

The server would then determine generate a message id/timestamp and persist each message. This guarantees the message is saved before sending to each participant.

Finally the server would then broadcast the message to the chat channel. This means all subscribers to the channel including the message sender would receive the message.